# How is a waste drain vent pipe vertical clearance measured?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, drain-waste-vent

In my jurisdiction, a waste drain vent pipe must terminate 6" above the roof (or another vertical surface if it's not sloped). Is this typically measured on the ridge side or the eave side? For a 4" vent (like mine), it would mean a difference of about 2.5" on my 7/12 roof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's measured on the high side (the nearest point or the shortest dimension).

Typical language:

> Vent pipes shall terminate not less than 6 inches above the roof, measured from the highest point where the vent intersects the roof.

[image]

<sup>[Image source](http://www.homeownersnetwork.com/booktopic/vent-exterior-terminations/)</sup>

Comment: Agree Highest point at the pipe not the ridge.

Comment: Thanks for making sure to point out the difference between my phrasing ("ridge side") vs the correct phrasing ("highest point").